# Is there investigation into foreign influence on the 2016 electoral college?

Tags: united-states, electoral-college, corruption

My understanding is Hillary won the popular vote by around 2.8 million votes. She lost the Electoral vote.The American people wanted Hillary for President it appears..but the Electoral College voted Trump in... Are they looking into the members of the Electoral College to see if they were persuaded? Because to me the American people didn't want Trump for president. If I'm wrong please enlighten me.

Comment: Blame California. Clinton won there by 4.27 million votes. As of 2013, California was the most populace state with 38 million individuals, Texas second with 26 million. Without California, Hillary Clinton loses the Popular vote. Learn about why the Electoral College is important; Further, look at the presidential results broken down by Congressional district.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Republicans have virtually no influence in CA government. Kamala Harris, the Senator who replaced Barbara Boxer, ran unopposed and the Democrats have a supermajority and the governorship.

Answer (score 16):

Zero electors who were supposed to vote for Hillary Clinton voted for Donald Trump instead.  So no electors could have been persuaded by Russia (or anyone) to switch to Donald Trump, because that simply didn't happen.

The reason why the electoral college differed from the popular vote is due to the structure of the electoral college.  The electoral college votes in forty-eight states (and the District of Columbia) are awarded to the statewide (districtwide) winner.  Two others award them by Congressional district, two to the statewide winner and one for each House district.  Trump won states with more electoral college votes than the states where Clinton won.

She ran up her vote total in DC, New York, and California where she didn't need the votes.  She lost states like Wisconsin, Michigan, Pennsylvania, North Carolina, and Florida where she did need votes.  Her overall margin in the popular vote is about the same as the vote margin in California.

Clinton won the most votes, what is called a plurality of the vote.  She did not win a majority.  A majority (51.8%) of Americans did not want her as president.  While a slightly larger majority did not want Trump, he did win the election by the established method.

All data from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_2016).

Comment: It might be worth restating the points in the last major paragraph, specifically about Americans not wanting Clinton/Trump, or at least the reasoning for those figures.  The issue's that many people voted for what they saw to be the lesser of two perceived evils, while others voted for the better of two perceived goods.

Comment: For numbers, [538's approval/disapproval of Trump](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-approval-ratings/) might be useful.  Looks like it was 45.5% approval vs. 41.3% disapproval back when he took office.  Just in case anyone's curious, it's showing 39.1% approve vs. 55.1% disapprove as the most recent figure.

Answer (score 2):

[This story](http://thehill.com/homenews/campaign/311107-two-texas-electors-abandoned-trump) details the number of electors who defected in the presidential election of 2016. None of the defecting electors voted for the other major candidate.

In short, Trump had two defecting electors, and Clinton had six defecting electors. Contrast that with the headline of the story, and draw what conclusions you wish.

The electoral college for presidential elections is to ensure that the heavily populated areas don't dominate the rest of the country. A candidate has to have a broad appeal across all areas of the country, not just the maximum number of votes.

The US Senate operates on the same principle, giving two senators for each state, regardless of the state's size or population.

Comment: "insure that the heavily populated areas don't dominate the rest of the country" — Except the number of electoral votes a state has is determined (indirectly) by its population, unlike the Senate.

Comment: @jwodder Yes, but the Electoral College limits that. California is the most populace state, with 38 million and 55 electoral votes; Wyoming is the least, with .5 million and 3 electoral votes. That is .7 million per vote in CA, versus .2 million per vote in Wyoming. The impact of California is restrained by the Electoral College.